# GraphQL: how does Apollo client caching work to keep data consistency with the server?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I'm using `apollo-client` with `apollo-cache-inmemory`.

Suppose I have 2 pages: *Item List* page and *Item Detail* page.

*Item List* page displays (by fetching the data using `client.query(...)`:

- Item A
- Item B
- Item C

When navigating to *Item Detail* page of Item B, I mutate Item B by using the mutation technique involving `store.readQuery` and `store.writeQuery` described here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#updating-after-a-mutation

Now, before navigating back to the *Item List* page, suppose that another user of my app did mutation to Item A.

My questions:

1. When I navigate back to *Item List* page, **do I get the data from the cache or from the server**? Does the `client.query(...)` always fetch data from the server?
2. If I got the data from the cache, **how can I then keep data consistency with the server**? (the goal is to always show updated item, e.g. Item A, in the list - synced with the server while optimizing caching)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the data synchronized even when it's changed by other users, you'll need to either always fetch from the server or implement subscriptions on both server and client. This way you'll be able to push new events when the data changes and have clients subscribe to these changes to keep their caches updates in real time.

Comment: Ah right, it's getting clearer now. But does the `client.query` call always fetch data from the server by default?

Comment: The client's behavior can be modified on a per-query basis using the [fetchPolicy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#optionsfetchpolicy) option. `cache-first` is the default.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've got it now. 